# Compactness in $\mathbb{R}^{X}$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, compactness

I'm reading a book chapter on weak topology, where the author identified the collection of all real functions on an abstract space $X$ with $\mathbb{R}^{X}$. I find it difficult to make sense out of the following claim:

> From the Tychonoff Product Theorem, it follows that a subset $\mathscr{F}$ of $\mathbb{R}^{X}$ is compact in the product topology if and only if it is closed and pointwise bounded.

I can see that since $\mathbb{R}^{X}$ is Hausdorff under the weak topology, for $\mathscr{F}$ to be compact it must be closed. When $\mathscr{F}$ is carried by the projection map into $R$, its image must also be compact, hence the pointwise-boundedness.

But I find it hard to understand the "if" part of the statement above. More importantly, how does it relate to the Tychonoff Product Theorem?

Am I missing something important here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\mathscr{F}$ is bounded at a point $x$, its projection at $x$ is contained in some compact interval $I_x$. If $\mathscr{F}$ is pointwise bounded, then $\mathscr{F} \subseteq \prod I_x$, which is compact. Thus if $\mathscr{F}$ is also closed, then it is a closed subset of the compact set $\prod I_x$, hence $\mathscr{F}$ is itself compact.